# sendFile return empty object express postman

Tags: node.js, express

I have a REST API  in NodeJs so i want create a method that send image, for now i have a static example but it don't work, my code is the following:

```
router.get('/image',function(req,res){
res.sendFile('img001.jpg', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../static/image') });
});
```

I'm check if it work using postman but the return is only `{}` I really don't sure but maybe the problem can de postman? how can check if the method is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all since its a GET request you can directly enter full url in your browser.

Its looks like everything is correct. Make sure you have `img001.jpg` in `path.join(__dirname, '../static/image')`

Also add error handler for sendFile and check if you are getting any error.

```
router.get('/image', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('img001.jpg', {
        root: path.join(__dirname, '../static/image')
    }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks the error was `code: 'ENOENT',` beacause the path was wrong